# Why i am gettng error while migrating the database

Tags: laravel

Before copying this project everything was ok but after copying this project to another laptop I am not able to migrate the database error

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'discussionforum.channels' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `channels`)

  at /opt/lampp/htdocs/discussionforum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:665
    661|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    662|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    663|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    664|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 665|             throw new QueryException(
    666|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    667|             );
    668|         }
    669| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))
      [internal]:0

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'discussionforum.channels' doesn't exist")
      /opt/lampp/htdocs/discussionforum/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:327

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

Comment: try with "php artisan migrate:fresh" and say about result

Comment: Are you certain that your table migrations are dated in the order you want them to be provisioned, from oldest to newest?  It sounds like you may have modifications (add, remove, or change fields or indexes) that are occurring before the table is created.  It also might be helpful to split any indexes into their own migrations that run after all of the tables are created.

Comment: It's difficult to see where the error is located with such little information. Try adding the related migration classes and also their names. It seems that you are executing them in the wrong order.

Comment: You should check `AppServiceProvider ` or other providers which boot before migrate, if you use some table or model in providers u not able to use migration when that table doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check `AppServiceProvider` or other providers which boot before migrate, if you use some table or model in providers u not able to use migration when that table doesn't exist.

If you look better there is error in

```
1   Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider))
      [internal]:0
```

Check providers which using models before any table exists.

If u insist to use model in provider, you should check is it exists before of usage, like this:

```
Schema::hasTable('mytable'); // off course schema must be imported.
```

If u post content of you're providers, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to preserve the current data
you could try resetting your data using

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

and/or delete and recreate your
"database.(sql extension)" file

Comment: this method didn't work